# Delete all the lines including and after nth occurance of pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

Basically what the title says, I have some large tsv file (approx. 20k lines) and I want to delete the rest of the files after a specific column matches a string a second time (including said line)

Comment: create a sample (say 10 lines) and add expected output along with what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0} $1=="yourstring"{if(++found==2)exit}' test.tsv
```

Where `$1` is the "specific column" and `yourstring` is the string you are searching for.

This prints each line and then checks for the occurrence of `yourstring` in the first column. If it finds it, it tests a variable `found` which we increment, to see if it hits 2. If so awk exits.

Edit: If instead you want to delete the second occurrence (as well as everything after), flipping the two blocks around will accomplish this:

```
 awk ' $1=="yourstring"{if(++found==2)exit}{print $0}' test.tsv
```

Comment: This prints the second matching line, the question says it should be deleted. Just move the print to the end to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

then

```
awk '{c+=/0$/}c>=2{exit}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Explanation: if regular expression matches line value is 1, else is 0, so I increase `c` value by 1 if there is match and by 0 if there is not match. I use `0$` meaning line ending with zero for demonstration purposes. If `c` value is bigger or equal 2 then I `exit` thus line where there is 2nd match and following are deleted. If not `exit` has been done yet I `print` line as-is.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tsv does not have quoted newlines or tabs, the logic for a (GNU) `sed` solution is quite simple but finding the column is harder than with `awk`:

```
sed -n -e '
    0,/BRE/bp
    //q
    :p
    p
' <test.tsv >out.tsv
```

With POSIX sed, it is a bit more complicated:

```
sed -n -e '
    /BRE/!bp
    :r
    p
    n
    //q
    br
    :p
    p
' <test.tsv >out.tsv
```

The methods wouldn't really scale if number of matches desired was higher, as sed can't really count.

---

In the code above, `BRE` should be replaced by a regex that matches n-1 columns and then the string being sought. For example, to find `the.needle` as 4th column (of 5 or more):

```
^\([^\t]*\t\)\{3\}the\.needle\t
```

If 4th column is final column:

```
\tthe\.needle$
```